# Google sheets - query cell value contains value in comma separated cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to query a group of say fruits so I'm grouped these into a comma-separated cell and I want to query that cell but I don't get any results. When I just one value in that cell says Apple it wants a result. I thought using contains would allow me to do that in a query? If not are they better methods?

Table

```
A B
Bob Apple
May Orange
Simon Apple
Sam Pear
Tom Grape
```

Query

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Sheet1'!$A2:$AB500, "select A,C,Y where D contains 'Staff' and (K='Y' or L='Y') and C contains '"&G7&"' ", 0),"None")
```

G7 contains 'Apple,Pear,Grape,Orange'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this part

```
C contains '"&G7&"'
```

to

```
C matches '"&SUBSTITUTE(G7, ",", "|")&"'
```

and see if that helps?

EDIT: if you have brackets in the range and in G7 try

```
 =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY({A:C, regexreplace(B:B, "\(|\)",)}, "select Col1 where Col3 contains 'Team' and Col4 matches '"&SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(D2, "\(|\)",), ",", "|")&"' ", 0),"None"))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: It doesn't like brackets for G7 if you apple (red), apple (green), Orange,..., etc it doesn't pick up any of the cells with the brackets

Comment: That is because brackets represent a capturing group in a regular expression. You can remove those brackets by replacing those brackets:: C matches '"&SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(G7, "\(|\)"; ), ",", "|")&"'

Comment: Thanks - that does make sense with it being an escaping parenthesis but I'm still getting the same results

Comment: Seems something went wrong in pasting. I added the part in my post. Please check it again.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this again - Sadly it's the same results so not getting the brackets

Comment: The brackets are in G7 or also in the range? Can you maybe share a spreadsheet with some sample data?

Comment: sure - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SSw9nRanpFtWh42eBhz1JeMHpZKZlrhEE52RQkPZ0V8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated the formula (see last one in my post). See if that works?

Comment: Thanks for trying again @JPV - Don't think anything has changed in the results and not sure if the post got updated?

Comment: Don't know what happened. Maybe I forgot to confirm the edit. Anyhow, the formula should be visible now.

Comment: If the forumla is based on other sheets it stops working - {code} =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY({Sheet2!A:C, regexreplace(Sheet2!B:B, "\(|\)",)}, "select Col1 where Col3 contains 'Team' and Col2 matches '"&SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(D2, "\(|\)",), ",", "|")&"' ", 0),"None"))  {code} .   - I've updated the spreadsheet with it  L18 - where would the forumla break here? Thanks

Comment: can you use the same formula between sheets? I wouldn't have thought pulling data from other sheets would break the regex?

Comment: In your new formula, change Col2 to Col4.. that should do it.

Comment: Awesome  - Interesting doesn't seem to like Col10 and above as in B20

Comment: Col10 ? Your current range is only 4 columns wide (A:C and B:B).

Comment: Sorry @JPV - Sheet didn't update but it's updated now

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to change the column where you want to find the match for the values in F3. Give the range A:M and the added column regexreplace(Sheet2!B:B, "\(|\)",) you would now have to refer to column 14 (13 columns in the range A:M + 1 column with the regexreplace in the array.